# Execute Anonymous and Custom Objects

Tags: execute-anonymous

To test updating a custom object field via a trigger, I'm executing an update in Execute Anonymous to test the code. My test works on standard objects (Contact), but it doesn't recognize my custom object (Project) which is also in a managed package.  Profiles allow me to update the object. The Error msg. is: Invalid Type:(Project). It references the 1st line 'List'. Please advise.

```
    List<Project> projs = [SELECT Id FROM Project Where   Project.PT_PIPROJ__PI_Outbound_Msg_Sent__c = True];     
for(Project project  :projs){ 
    Project.PT_PIPROJ__PI_Outbound_Msg_Sent__c = False; } 
    update projs;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom objects in a managed package org have a namespace prefix (e.g. `yourns__`) automatically added and the custom object suffix (`__c`) automatically added.

So if you created an object called "Project", the API name you need to use in Execute Anonymous would be `yourns__Project__c`.

So if the managed package namespace is "PT_PIPROJ":

```
List<PT_PIPROJ__Project__c> projs = [
        SELECT Id
        FROM PT_PIPROJ__Project__c
        Where PT_PIPROJ__PI_Outbound_Msg_Sent__c = True
        ];     
for (PT_PIPROJ__Project__c proj : projs) { 
    proj.PT_PIPROJ__PI_Outbound_Msg_Sent__c = False;
} 
update projs;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this documentation which has details about Custom objects in Salesforce and its naming conventions:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_custom_objects.htm

> In the API, the names of custom objects include a suffix of two underscores followed by a lowercase “c” . For example, a custom object labeled “Issue” in the Salesforce user interface is Issue__c in that organization’s WSDL.